# TCPTransportConnection memory leak

Tags: java, performance, memory, memory-leaks, apache-camel

I'm troubleshooting my app memory leak overtime. I start my app and leave it alone for a couple of days without sending a single request.

App is a simple one, it has some CFX-endpoints raised and Camel-routes listening to them.

When I start my app, heap grows rapidly and reaches maximum at about 300 Mb.

[image]

In a couple of days, the heap average size is about 500 Mb with max about 750 Mb.

Here is profiling result:

[image]

I've looked at the stacktrace for the heavy surviving objects:

[image]

All of them lead to TCPTransport.ConnectionHandler or it's co-package classes.

Used library versions and pom:

Java 8 (1.8.0_172)

```
<properties>
    <fabric8.version>2.3.7.fuse-000036-redhat-2</fabric8.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>fabric8-project-bom-camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${fabric8.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>

    <!-- CAMEL dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-swagger-java-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here's cfx-enpoint config:

```
   <cxf:cxfEndpoint address="/{{cxf.version}}/MyService"
       endpointName="a:MyServicePort" id="MyService"
       serviceClass="mypackage.here"
       serviceName="a:MyService"
       wsdlURL="my.wsdl" xmlns:a="http://localhost/v1/MyService">
       <cxf:inInterceptors>
           <ref bean="wssSecurityInterceptor"/>
       </cxf:inInterceptors>
   </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Does anyone have an idea, where memory is leaking?

Answer (score 0):

did see the same issue, revert back to tomcat. Switched to G1 it helped a bit, but it slowed the transaction response time at some intervals of GC.